# jQuery: difference between .click() AND .on("click")

Tags: javascript, binding, methods, jquery

I usually use

```
$(selector).click(...
```

But some people recommend me to use this instead:

```
$(selector).on("click", function(...
```

Or `$(selector).live("click"...`  (Deprecated)

I read the manual, but my begginer's mind couldn't understand it. I got confused with all the terminology they used. I still do not know the difference nor why to use `.on()`

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: From the docs: *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For equivalents to older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), and .live()."*

Answer (score 34):

At the end of the day, every event is bound to *some* element in the DOM. In the case of `.bind`, you're binding directly to the element (or elements) in your jQuery object. If, for example, your jQuery object contained 100 elements, you'd be binding 100 event listeners.

In the case of `.live`, `.delegate`, and `.on`, a *single* event listener is bound, generally on one of the topmost nodes in the DOM tree: `document`, `document.documentElement` (the `<html>` element), or `document.body`. Because DOM events bubble up through the tree, an event handler attached to the `body` element can actually receive click events originating from any element on the page. So, rather than binding 100 events you could bind just one.

For a small number of elements (fewer than five, say), binding the event handlers directly is likely to be faster (although performance is unlikely to be an issue). For a larger number of elements, always use `.on`.

The other advantage of `.on` is that if you add elements to the DOM you don't need to worry about binding event handlers to these new elements. Take, for example, an HTML list:

```
<ul id="todo">
  <li>buy milk</li>
  <li>arrange haircut</li>
  <li>pay credit card bill</li>
</ul>
```

Next, some jQuery:

```
// Remove the todo item when clicked.
$('#todo').children().click(function () {
  $(this).remove()
})
```

Now, what if we add a todo?

```
$('#todo').append('<li>answer all the questions on SO</li>')
```

Clicking this todo item will not remove it from the list, since it doesn't have any event handlers bound. If instead we'd used `.on`, the new item would work without any extra effort on our part. Here's how the `.on` version would look:

```
$('#todo').on('click', 'li', function (event) {
  $(event.target).remove()
})
```

Comment: why did you use **$(event.target).remove();** instead of **$(this).remove();**? Also, I tried it in JSFiddle and could not make it work :-( [http://jsfiddle.net/u6qWs/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/u6qWs/1/)

Comment: @Omar Good point about `event.target`. At the time I wrote this I was not sure of the binding of `this` within event handlers passed to `.on`. Having just read the method's documentation I now realize that `this` and `event.type` will refer to the same object in this case (but don't in all cases).

Comment: @Omar The `.on` method was added in jQuery 1.7 which has just been released. Your fiddle uses jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: @davidchambers oops! I fixed the fiddle. Thanks for pointing it out. IT'S ALIVE!!!  [http://jsfiddle.net/u6qWs/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/u6qWs/4/)         By the way, your sample is great, but it's missing a semicolon ";" at the end of every line.

Comment: A little observation using the click() method on children "$('#todo').children()" with the above mentioned function will remove the children object itself.Hence no children object= no object for an event. On the other hand using the .on method on #todo will not remove the #todo object but target all 'li elements'..I think this is the point that should be brought out..the .on click method can take elements as arguments

Answer (score 12):

In the plain `.click(...` if the target of the selector changes on the fly (e.g via some ajax response) then you'd need to assign the behavior again.

On `.live(...` the behavior will be automatically be reapplied on the selector.

The `.on(...` is very new (jQuery 1.7) and it can cover the `live` scenario using delegated events which is a faster way to attach behavior anyway.

Comment: So...If I **clone** an element, or dynamically **create content with ajax**, If I use **.click()** wont work on the new content, but **.on("click")** it will work? I think it's called binding methods/events?

Comment: Also `.on()` can be used to attach multiple events simultaneously using a map.

Comment: @Omar: Yes, assuming you have got the delegation correctly. E.g if you are talking about trs inside a table then you need to do `$("#myTable").on("click", "tr", ...`. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @pedram-behroozi I do not even know what a jQuery map is...it uses a GPS? :p.  Aaaaa...how do you attach multible events simultaneously using a map?

Comment: @cherouvim I read api.jquery.com/on ...but like I explained, I am a beginner and do not understand all the terminology they used. I got more confused :-(

Comment: Try looking for jQuery tutorials and, why not, a beginners book.

Answer (score 8):

The only difference is that `.click()` will be applied on the elements that exist in the DOM with that particular selector (only the ones that **already** exist ).
In the other hand `.on(selector ,"click",callback);` will be applied on all the elements that match that selector 
even in the future,
let me give an example :

```
$('p').click(function(){
$(this).next('<p>this is a copy of the previous paragraph </p>');
});
```

If you click on the paragraph that says "this is a copy of the previous paragraph" (the new one ) you don't get the result that you want which is to add a paragraph next to the clicked one  because it was not  there at the beginning

but if you use

```
$('p').on("click",function(){
$(this).next('<p>this is a copy of the previous paragraph </p>');
});
```

you will get what you want (because `.on` or `.delegate` find the match even with the new ones)