# jQuery Click event not fireing

Tags: jquery

In a nutshell, I have a click event and it doesn't seem to be firing.  jQuery is being loaded, and this is what I have for the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(".ajaxForm").click(function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="right">
<span class="ajaxForm" type="ajax"><span>Get Quote</span></span>
</div>
```

It's probably just me being stupid, it's been a long day.  Anything stand out as being wrong?  I've checked, double checked and triple checked the selector.

Comment: Are you 100% sure on your $('.ajaxForm') selector?  If you use Firebug or the Chrome console and run it, does it actually return the element(s) on the page you're expecting?  Could you post the HTML markup from the page?  At least the form section.  Edit: I just now realized you said you double/triple checked the selector. Regardless, the markup would be helpful.

Comment: did you try alert('click'); ?

Comment: Your code creates a function that is never called.

Comment: @Gromer - I'm sure the selector is correct.  Just posted the corresponding HTML as well. I can see the class when I inspect element in Firefox as well.

Comment: can you try alert('click');  as bobek said or $(".ajaxForm").hide() or some thing other than click to just to see you are getting into document.ready function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created the anonymous function, but you forgot to invoke it (self-invoking function). In this case, you will have to call it directly with the jQuery object as parameter. Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(".ajaxForm").click(function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Obviously this function has to be called after that the DOM is loaded or after the `.ajaxForm` elements (otherwise he won't find the elements to attach the event on and the event won't be attached to the elements you want).

If you want this function in the HEAD (or another JavaScript file), you will have to this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ajaxForm").click(function() {
            console.log("click");
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Thank you! Spot on, how I missed that I don't know.... probably due to the whole day in front of a screen staring at various languages.

Answer (score 6):

function($) is incorrect. Try $(function(){});

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: It is correct, however it isn't a self invoking function as the TS wants. You can use this if you have for example multiple frameworks included, and you would like to use the $ function in your jQuery code...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajaxForm").click(function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    $(".ajaxForm").click(function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
```

Notice the difference in the syntax with the first line of code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, still no change though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw a spanner in the works...

```
$(".ajaxForm").on('click',function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

On (similar to live) is actually [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8018769/94278) then `.click()` and doesnt require the DOM to be ready