# click event is not working while onclick is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

in my code i have applied click event on an img tag and it is not working at all but when i applied the same code for onclick on same tag it started working perfectly . 
following is the code :-

```
   // closing div with click on img .
   $('img.close_url').click(function(){
       alert('close');
       $('div.urlResult').hide();
       $('input#hidden_url_title').val();
       $('input#hidden_url_content').val();
       $('input#hidden_is_url').val(0);
   });

   // closing div by applying onclick on img tag 
   function closeUrl()
   {
       $('div.urlResult').hide();
       $('input#hidden_url_title').val();
       $('input#hidden_url_content').val();
       $('input#hidden_is_url').val(0);
    }
```

Html:

//content to be loaded in #results element

```
var content = '<div class = "extracted_url">'+ inc_image +'<div class="extracted_content"><h4><a href="'+extracted_url+'" target="_blank">'+data.title+'</a><img class = "close_url"  src ="'+IMAGE_PATH+'/cross-grey.png"/></h4><p>'+data.content+'</p><div class="thumb_sel"><span class="prev_thumb" id="thumb_prev">&nbsp;</span><span class="next_thumb" id="thumb_next">&nbsp;</span> </div><span class="small_text" id="total_imgs">'+img_arr_pos+' of '+total_images+'</span><span class="small_text">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choose a Thumbnail</span></div></div>';
```

/* above is the html that I am adding with javascript function . And this is not inside .ready */

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678496/jquery-click-not-working-jquery-onclick-working-fine
I think it is not working because image is being build after adding a url and that too is initially hidden . so i have to use .on("click",function(){}); instead of simple click .

Comment: I just tried you scenario in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4JFkT/ and the click seems to work for me.

Comment: @Simer your click seems to work fine. have you included `jQuery` library ?

Comment: may be because you have added the html initially and in my code the html is being added at run time .

Comment: @Simer Dom may is not ready it seems when you are adding event

Comment: @shadow i have added my code inside .ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running the `.click` code before the `<a>` tag is in the DOM (i.e. before the DOM ready event.

Make sure that code is wrapped in an on ready event, like this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

  // closing div with click on img .
  $('img.close_url').click(function(){
    ..
  });

});
```

Comment: I have put it inside $( document ).ready( function() {}); but even then its not working . where as its working for other tags which are placed nearby this img tag . I am referring http://api.jquery.com/on/ .

Comment: Please check the edited part of my question . thanks for the help @nick

Comment: In order to help further I would need to see all the code that is going on. Where is that "content" variable being declared, and how is it being used.. can you post all the code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks @nick .It now started working when i wrote it like this  $('div.viewed-profile-outer').on( "click","img.close_url",function(){
   $('div.urlResult').hide();
   $('input#hidden_url_title').val();
   $('input#hidden_url_content').val();
   $('input#hidden_is_url').val(0);
   $('textarea#post_box').val();
  });