# How to create click event on random "div" inside a main "div"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one main "Div" on which after clicking it gets split into n X n matrix. On every click inside it with a random colour div. Until here it's fine, now I want to create a click function on that random colourful div which currently is on any where inside the whole main "div"..

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var no = 1,
    $m = $(".main_div"),
    size = 200;

  $m.live('click', function() {
    no++;
    var n = no * no,
      i, _size;
    $m.empty();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      $m.append($('<div title=' + i + '/>'));
    _size = size / no;
    $m.find('> div').css({
      width: _size,
      height: _size
    });

    var colors = ["#FFFFFF", "#CC00CC", "#CC6699", "#0099CC", "#FF99FF"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length),
      randomTotalbox = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.main_div div').length);
    $m.find("div:eq(" + randomTotalbox + ")").css("background-color", colors[rand]);
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  });
});
```

```css
  .main_div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #9F0;
  }
  .main_div > div {
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div" id="demo">

</div>
```

Here is a fiddle...[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjay_007/Le7d5jad/)

Comment: Save the object for the "random `<div>`" into a variable as soon as you find it, then do whatever you want with it. No rocket science.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev-I tried that also but it was not working from me...Please see the fiddle of the same..[link](http://jsfiddle.net/twe53zuf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

so you are saying that the clickable div is added to the DOM whenever you click(for example on a button )

that means that those divs were not there in the beginning so you can  use

the **Babak Naffas**  answer  and also the **.delegate** method

example

```
$('body').delegate('.main_div > div','click',function(){
  // here goes your instructions

});
```

for more details you can check: 
[jQuery: difference between .click() AND .on("click")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018760/jquery-difference-between-click-and-onclick)

Comment: @hamism- Yea! I guess u r getting me 80% correct..i  am saying i hve already that random div inside in my main div..So i just want click on tht random dov only rather then anywhere in the main div..Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/twe53zuf/1/)

Comment: you can add a class to all the divs that you want to be clickable  for example class ='clickable' then in your jquery code use $('.main_div .clickable')  i hope that is what you want to achieve

Comment: @hamism- Actually i don't want clickable div at predefined position..It should be at random place..Please see the following link..it's a game .But i am trying exactly same..[link](http://106.186.25.143/kuku-kube/en-3/)

Comment: @sanjay but when you are appending ('<div title=' + i + '/>') to $m you don't know the position of the new inserted div and the class that i was talking about is added like this `('<div title=' + i + ' class="clickable" />')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for an event to be triggered when the NxN `<div>`s that make up the matrix are clicked, you could try

```
 $(".main_div > div").on('click', function (evt) { ... } );
```

This will attach the function (the 2nd parameter) to the click event of the `<div>` from the matrix just like the CSS class you have with the same selector.

Comment: Yea!Right now also i am able to click on that n X n div that are formed.Bur specifically i am expecting click on the random colorful   "div" which is formed on evry click.Please check following feddle code of same.So that you may get idea exactly what I am expecting..
Thanks for giving me ur time..[link](http://jsfiddle.net/twe53zuf/1/)