# Dynamic double menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day anyone who is reading. I'm asking for help in situation that I can't solve.... 
I tried to do a double navigation menu - click on one of the first navigation menu will load in block "top_menu" - options from the second menu; and option on second menu will load the content to block content.

the dynamical click I realize in the next function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link_from_first_menu').click(function () {
        $("#top_menu").load("first_option_from_second_menu.php");
        return false;
    });
});
```

So, that part is working, I mean, I loaded the second menu from the first perfectly, but when I have the similar function to load the content from the second menu it doesn't load the content...

```
$('#link_from_second_menu').click(function () {
    $("#content").load("content_from_second_menu.html");
    return false;
});
```

So the result, I have a first menu and second, but can't load the content from second. Please help me realize it or give me please other variant to do it.

Comment: .load("content_from_second_menu");  is content_from_second_menu should be content_from_second_menu.php? or what is suppose to be?

Comment: yes yes, my mistake when i copied from code...

Comment: is $('#link_from_second_menu')  come from first_option_from_second_menu.php?

Comment: yes.... I have two blocks for menu and one for content.... when you click on link on first menu load page.php - with second menu, when you click on second menu - load content.html

Comment: check my answer and if that code not working .. just check the path for your content_from_second_menu.html

Comment: yes the comment below is work... it is work, thanks for everyone... if you have better ideas to realize it please feel free to write for future... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you can try .on('click')

```
$(document).on('click','#link_from_second_menu',function () {
    $("#content").load("content_from_second_menu.html");
    return false;
});
```

instead of

```
$('#link_from_second_menu').click(function () {
    $("#content").load("content_from_second_menu.html");
    return false;
});
```

may my answer help you .. and always used to use .on('click') instead of.click() specially  after append or load

Comment: yes it is work... wow thanks... can you explain why my variant didn't work?

Comment: @alex_mike  read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018760/jquery-difference-between-click-and-onclick